# can't connect to Azure SQL using SQLAlchemy with pymssql

Tags: python, azure, sqlalchemy, pymssql

Using SQLAlchemy to connect to SQL Server on Azure.
I can access it via JDBC using SQL Workbench/J from same IP.(opened the IP in Azure)

Using the string:

```
mssql+pymssql://username:password@SQLservername.database.windows.net
```

Getting:

> (pymssql.OperationalError) (20002, b'DB-Lib error message 20002, severity 9:\nAdaptive Server connection failed (nibisql1.database.windows.net:1433)\n') (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)

I tried all variations, but none of them work.

1. any idea why?
2. How do I pass parameters such as databasename?

Comment: **(1)** What operating system are you using? **(2)** Did you install pymssql using `pip install pymssql`?

Comment: I got the exact same error with `pymssql` connecting to Azure. The only way I found to beat this is to switch to `pyodbc` over `unixodbc` (or `msodbc`, whichever suits you needs better). That is if you're on Linux. Works perfectly.

Comment: Actually, after a bit more trial and error I found it's not at all straightforward with `pyodbc` , but it is possible to get it to work

Comment: are you using linux? and did you install the drivers for mssql ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
    mssql+pymssql://username@SQLservername:password@SQLservername.database.windows.net
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to proplery encode/quote parameters in the URL.

```
from urllib.parse import quote
conn_string = f"mssql+pymssql://{quote(user)}:{quote(password)}@{quote(server)}/{quote(db_name)}"
```